# PhanomJS get stuck [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 90

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to load a page "https://sliderdevatha.engageclick.com/optus/agent.html?chatId=someChatUniqueId" using phantom 1.9.8

here is my ssl.js

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = "https://sliderdevatha.engageclick.com/optus/agent.html?chatId=someChatUniqueId";
page.open(url, function (status) {
    console.log('========================');
    console.log(status);
    console.log('========================');
    //Page is loaded!
    phantom.exit();
});
```

here is the command that i'm trying to run

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --debug=true --ssl-protocol=any  ssl.js
```

here is the output, it gets stuck at

> WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 90

what am i doing wrong? And is there a way to read half or whatever the content is loaded till now?

```
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store cookies (use option '--cookies-file=<filename>' to enable persisten cookie storage)
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      0 objectName : ""
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      1 cookiesFile : ""
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      2 diskCacheEnabled : "false"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      4 ignoreSslErrors : "true"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      5 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      6 outputEncoding : "UTF-8"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      7 proxyType : "http"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      8 proxy : ":1080"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      9 proxyAuth : ":"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      10 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      11 webSecurityEnabled : "false"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      12 offlineStoragePath : ""
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      13 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      14 printDebugMessages : "true"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      15 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      16 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      17 sslProtocol : "any"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      18 sslCertificatesPath : ""
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      19 webdriver : ":"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      20 webdriverLogFile : ""
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      21 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      22 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : ""
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG]      script: "test.js"
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/_coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/package.json" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./lexer.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././rewriter.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./parser.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./nodes.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././scope.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./././helpers.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/././lexer.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/../coffee-script/./lib/coffee-script/./././rewriter.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r") ) )
Loading a web page
2015-01-27T14:53:27 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
2015-01-27T14:53:29 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 11
2015-01-27T14:53:29 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 12
2015-01-27T14:53:29 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 13
2015-01-27T14:53:29 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 15
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 16
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 19
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 20
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 22
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 24
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 26
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 29
2015-01-27T14:53:30 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 30
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 33
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 36
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 38
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 40
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 40
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 42
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 44
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 45
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 46
2015-01-27T14:53:31 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 47
2015-01-27T14:53:32 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 48
2015-01-27T14:53:32 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 48
2015-01-27T14:53:32 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 49
2015-01-27T14:53:32 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
2015-01-27T14:53:32 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 51
2015-01-27T14:53:32 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 53
2015-01-27T14:53:32 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 67
2015-01-27T14:53:33 [WARNING] QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
2015-01-27T14:53:33 [WARNING] QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
2015-01-27T14:53:33 [WARNING] QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)
2015-01-27T14:53:33 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 68
2015-01-27T14:53:33 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 72
2015-01-27T14:53:33 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 75
2015-01-27T14:53:34 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 77
2015-01-27T14:53:34 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 79
2015-01-27T14:53:34 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 82
2015-01-27T14:53:34 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 84
2015-01-27T14:53:34 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 87
2015-01-27T14:53:34 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 89
2015-01-27T14:53:35 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 90
2015-01-27T14:53:36 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 90
2015-01-27T14:53:36 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Saved "AWSELB=6F318DF30E4F6AAB00FE33D1E950AE429C1B37FC4757AC83BCCB09155F01E4F4F3380B8AFF044E5CAC59F5FACA1BD61A0DEAD6DBA9B97B9345871A93F54A548E864609258851E2D5E7FA8CB08E24DA53043DCA0E2D; secure; domain=.engageclick.com; path=/"
2015-01-27T14:53:36 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 90
2015-01-27T14:53:36 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Saved "AWSELB=6F318DF30E4F6AAB00FE33D1E950AE429C1B37FC4757AC83BCCB09155F01E4F4F3380B8AFF044E5CAC59F5FACA1BD61A0DEAD6DBA9B97B9345871A93F54A548E864609258851E2D5E7FA8CB08E24DA53043DCA0E2D; secure; domain=.engageclick.com; path=/"
```

Comment: Are you getting any HTTP errors when viewing the page in a browser?

Comment: No, there were no HTTP errors.

Answer (score 2):

Got a fix at [phantomjs.org](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html)

Basically in that page there was a AJAX request in every 5 second, to check and update the page. Which makes phantomJS thinks that the page is not fully loaded.

by setting "settings.resourceTimeout" to some value, say 3000 (ms), fixes it.

Comment: I was searching for this answer for a couple of hours. Thanks!